# Problem in designing an algorithm that moves structures in an array[][] in a certain way

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I am a beginner C programmer.
I have been failing to find an algorythm that can solve the following problem:

> On an array "board[x][y]" with two dimensions, which contains
> following arranged elements:
>
> **Floor** (*white*), **Item** (*blue*), **Backpack** (*green*) and **Player** (*orange*), the Player can move and can move Items by directly "touching" them, in a way that they move into the same direction and
> stay attatched. "Touching" is defined by an Item being on either of
> the four sides of the Player.
>
> [Graphic 1 describing predicted movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djmgP.png)
>
> If there is a Backpack attatched to the Player, the Backpack itself
> acts as kind of a sticky attachment, moving all Items attached to that
> Backpack, including other Backpacks.
>
> [Graphic 2 describing predicted movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYEBq.png)

Is there an algorithm that can sucessfully move the  resulting "structures" formable by the rules, only moving Items "attached"?  If you can help me find a way or guide me on a path, I'd be very happy to learn about it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Suggestion: every element except Floor is the same type of `struct` with a member identifying which type. You can associate them into groups by forming linked lists.

Comment: Please, algorithm.

Comment: What if an attached item (not being a backpack) is against another item and you try to move ?

Answer (score 0):

Store in a list the positions of the player and of the attached items and backpacks. When you perform a move, all elements in the list move. After the move, consider the player and backpacks in the list, and add the neighboring items or backpacks *that are not already there*.

[But see my second comment.]